# using an array in a loop

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

=(DAYS(ArrayFormula(A10:A20),TODAY()))

Trying to get the days remaining as the output for B10:B20 to the corresponding dates in A10:A20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap in ArrayFormula your whole formula and not the range in particular:

```
=ArrayFormula(Days(A10:A20,TODAY()))
```

[image]